# Egg muffin tin cooking

Tags: food-safety, eggs

I make egg muffins in a muffin tin, using cubed ham, green pepper, onion etc. plus of course beaten eggs.   How long can I keep these in the fridge after they have been baked in the oven.  I've tried after 3 days and they still taste fine, I just want to know the safety factor

Comment: Would you mind posting your recipe and method? It always helps with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I always limit any refrigerated leftovers to 3days...any thing beyond that throw it out. The ingredients you mentioned are all safe for consumption during that time as long as the egg is thoroughly cooked to an internal temp of 160